# MFMailComposeViewController without Mail app installed?

Tags: ios, email, ios10, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Now that apps like Apple's "Mail" app can be deleted in iOS 10, what will happen when a developer attempts to initialize and present `MFMailComposeViewController` and the default Mail app is not installed and configured on the device?

If the app crashes, what is the best way to check for this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On iOS 12 and above, `canSendMail()` will return `true` even if the Mail app is not installed.  The `MFMailComposeViewController` will be presented, but the user will be unable to send mail.

On iOS versions below 12:

It looks like `MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()` will return false, and `MFMailComposeViewController()` will cause a crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS).  Use the `canSendMail()` check to determine if the device can show a `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Comment: Have You found a way to compose email via another installed mail app ( to handle the case when the user has deleted the native mail app )?

Comment: @GeorgiBoyadzhiev You should look at the documentation for the other apps.  There may be a deep link structure for apps like Gmail and Outlook.

Comment: As of iOS 12 `canSendMail()` will return true even if the Mail app is not installed. This will allow the `MFMailComposeViewController` to appear but the send button is disabled.

Comment: Hey @AndyHeard, thanks for the update.  I haven't looked at this answer since iOS 10 Beta 1, so I've updated it to reflect the behavior in iOS 12.