# Will UILocalNotification crash on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilocalnotification, ios10

This is current [UILocalNotification class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/) and this is iOS 10 [UserNotification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications#symbols) which apple just announced in wwdc 16.

Will the old apps using `UILocalNotification` will crash on iOS 10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a `UILocalNotification` object will not cause a crash on an iOS 10 device (I just tried it with the Xcode 8 beta).  Xcode will warn you that `UILocalNotification` was deprecated as of iOS 10 and `UNNotificationRequest` in the UserNotifications module should be used instead.  It is strongly encouraged to migrate your code to use `UNNotificationRequest` if you are targeting iOS 10 and above.

Comment: my  Xcode 8 beta download is in progress ..... I asked the question because I am extremely curious to know what will happen to my app :) ..... thanks a lot for answering with confirmation :)

Comment: No worries!  It's a valid question.  In fact, there are some weird crashes that can occur on iOS 10.  Like if you remove the Mail app from the phone and call `MFMailComposeViewController() ` your app will crash.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37800021/2415822) question.

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing, In UILocalNotification we use NSCalendarUnitMinute..... but I can't find in doc ... how can I use NSCalendarUnitMinute like repetition in iOS 10  UserNotification

Comment: @S.J you should ask a new question.

Comment: please view the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804287/how-to-use-nscalendarunitminute-like-repetition-in-ios-10-usernotification