# Repeat local notification for specific date iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have local notifications that fire up for specific date, for example, next monday. What i want is, to repeat this every monday. How to achieve that? Code i currently use:

```
 if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"10.0")) {

        /* Trigger date */


        NSDate *date = [[NSDate date] mt_dateSecondsAfter:15];
        NSDateComponents *triggerDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                                         components:NSCalendarUnitYear +
                                         NSCalendarUnitMonth + NSCalendarUnitDay +
                                         NSCalendarUnitHour + NSCalendarUnitMinute +
                                         NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:date];

        UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:triggerDate
                                                                                                          repeats:NO];

        /* Set notification */

        UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
        content.body = @"Время вставать с Ретро ФМ";
        content.categoryIdentifier = NotificationCategoryIdent;
        content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
        NSString *identifier = @"LocalNotification";
        UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                              content:content
                                                                              trigger:trigger];

        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
            }
        }];
    }
    else {

        // Code for old versions

        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        [notification setAlertBody:@"Время вставать с Ретро ФМ"];
        [notification setCategory:NotificationCategoryIdent];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work with this code?

Comment: just make repeats:NO to repeats:YES

Comment: @Koen its work, i want it to be repeated every monday/month/day

Comment: @Gagan_iOS if i do so, how it will know when it should repeat? Next day, hour, minute, week?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set an NSCalendarUnitMinute repeatInterval on iOS 10 UserNotifications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804287/how-do-i-set-an-nscalendarunitminute-repeatinterval-on-ios-10-usernotifications)

Comment: you have to set it on weekly basis from date components

Comment: repeatInterval,NSCalendarUnitWeekday will help you

Comment: @DSDharma yes it does solve problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace this in your code

```
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:triggerDate
                                                                                                          repeats:YES];
```

Comment: what exactly will be the date it repeat and fire date? And next date after fire date?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code:

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(@"10.0")) {

        /* Trigger date */


        NSDate *date = [[NSDate date] mt_dateSecondsAfter:15];
        NSDateComponents *triggerDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                                         components:NSCalendarUnitYear +
                                         NSCalendarUnitMonth + NSCalendarUnitDay +
                                         NSCalendarUnitHour + NSCalendarUnitMinute +
                                         NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:date];

        UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:triggerDate
                                                                                                          repeats:YES];

        /* Set notification */

        UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
        content.body = @"Время вставать с Ретро ФМ";
        content.categoryIdentifier = NotificationCategoryIdent;
        content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
        NSString *identifier = @"LocalNotification";
        UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                              content:content
                                                                              trigger:trigger];

        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
            }
        }];
    }
    else {

        // Code for old versions

        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        [notification setAlertBody:@"Время вставать с Ретро ФМ"];
        [notification setCategory:NotificationCategoryIdent];
        [notification setRepeatCalendar:NSCalendarUnitWeekday];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
    }
```

Comment: what is difference?

Comment: UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:triggerDate
                                                                                                          repeats:YES];

Comment: and 
        [notification setRepeatCalendar:NSCalendarUnitWeekday];

Answer (score 1):

The answer given , will work fine for iOS greater than Or equal.   But for lower version (as question has if else clause) it will not work. For Bellow iOS it will

localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay

This set notification for every day