# MFMailComposeViewController both send and cancel do not work

Tags: swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() is true, gmail screen comes up with correct recipient email ID, subject, and body. But send button is disabled. Also when I press Cancel button slider comes up with two options: delete and cancel. Delete does not work, and I cannot get back from mail composer to my previous controller.

Gmail is setup on my iphone and works fine. I cannot figure out what is wrong, can someone please help?

```
MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    if (selectedEntry!.notifyType == "Email") {
        let mailComposeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        let target:String = (selectedEntry?.targetString)!
        mailComposeVC.setToRecipients([target])
        mailComposeVC.setSubject("Test")
        mailComposeVC.setMessageBody("Hello ", isHTML: false)
        // present the message view controller
        self.present(mailComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
} else {
    print("MAIL services are not available")
    return
}



func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?)
{
    switch (result)
    {
    case .sent:
        print("email sent.")
        break
    case .cancelled:
        print("email cancelled.")
        break
    case .failed:
        print("failed sending email")
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Did you implement the required delegate method as documented?

Comment: Yes  func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        switch (result) {
            case .sent:
                print("email sent.")
                break
            case .cancelled:
                print("email cancelled.")
                break
            case .failed:
                print("failed sending email")
                break
            default:
                break
        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: The delete works now. But the send button is still grayed out.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. [Edit] your question with all relevant details.

Comment: sorry, I did that now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `MFMailComposeViewController` is powered by the native Mail app. Taken from the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller):

> If the user opts to send the message, the message is queued in the
>   user’s Mail app outbox. The Mail app is ultimately responsible for
>   sending the message.

Since a Gmail account is setup on the device, `canSendMail` will return true even if the Mail app is "uninstalled" from the device. The app isn't really uninstalled, but hidden. If you try to check that the app exists in the following fashion you will get a false positive.

```
let mailURL = URL(string: "mailto:?to=\(emailAddress)")!
let canSendEmail = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL)
```

Opening your validated url with `UIApplication.shared.open(mailURL)` will present an alert asking if you would like to reinstall the app.

[Restore "Mail"? alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpheS.png)

According to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37800118/11272613), this issue only exists in iOS 12 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Working well with Swift 5.

Firstly, make an extension of the viewController used to send the email:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import MessageUI
import LocalAuthentication

extension viewControllerThatSendsTheEmail: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{
  func mailComposeController( _ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result:MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?)
   {
    if let _ = error
    {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
        return
    }
    switch result
    {
    case.cancelled:
        print("CANCELLED")
    case.failed:
        print("FAILED")
    case.saved:
        print("SAVED")
    case.sent:
        print("EMAIL SENT")
    @unknown default:
        fatalError()
    }
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
  }
}
```

Then your function:

```
@objc func sendEmailButtonTap()
{
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
        else
    {
        return
    }
    let sending = MFMailComposeViewController()
    sending.mailComposeDelegate = self
    sending.setToRecipients(["awesomeDeveloper@apple.com"])
    sending.setSubject("AWRSOME APP")
    sending.setMessageBody("THIS APP IS SO AWESOME!", isHTML: false)
    present(sending, animated: true)
}
```