# Send email using react native (with attachments, android)

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, smtp

You need to send an email from the app to react native.

Used *react-native-mailcore*, but it can't attach files. And this is my main task

How else can I send email with files via smtp?

Comment: It's easier to write your own module
https://github.com/Andrew-Lomakin/react-native-email-smtp

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, so i ended up making my own library: [react-native-smtp-mailer](https://github.com/angelos3lex/react-native-smtp-mailer).

You connect to an smtp server with your credentials to send email to recipients, with the ability to add html body, attachments etc(ios+android). In fact it's a bridge of main functions of ios mailcore2 and android javamail.

Hope this help others too.

Answer (score -1):

How about [react-native-mail](https://github.com/esutton/react-native-mail) ?

Its is "a wrapper on top of MFMailComposeViewController from iOS and Mail Intent on android"

```
  var Mailer = require('NativeModules').RNMail;

  var MailExampleApp = React.createClass({
    handleHelp: function() {
      Mailer.mail({
        subject: 'need help',
        recipients: ['support@example.com'],
        body: '',
        attachment: {
          path: '',  // The absolute path of the file from which to read data.
          type: '',   // Mime Type: jpg, png, doc, ppt, html, pdf
          name: '',   // Optional: Custom filename for attachment
        }
      }, (error, event) => {
          if(error) {
            AlertIOS.alert('Error', 'Could not send mail. Please send a mail to support@example.com');
          }
      });
    },  
    render: function() {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={row.handleHelp}
              underlayColor="#f7f7f7">
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={require('image!announcement')} style={styles.image} />
          </View>
       </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I've seen this implementation. smtp must be inside the application

Comment: For MFMailComposeViewController to work, you need to have the official Mail.app installed and configured. Users who do not have Mail.app installed won't be able to send e-mails with react-native-mail.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800021/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-without-mail-app-installed

Answer (score -1):

First you need to install react-native-mail for send emails.

import Mailer from 'react-native-mail';

`handleEmail = (url) => {
        Mailer.mail({
            subject: 'Screenshot',
            recipients: ['example@gmail.com'],
            ccRecipients: ['example1@gmail.com'],
            //bccRecipients: ['supportBCC@example.com'],
            body: '<b>Hello</b><p>Please check attached screenshot.</p>',
            isHTML: true,
            attachment: {
                path: url,  // The absolute path of the file from which to read data.
                type: 'png',   // Mime Type: jpg, png, doc, ppt, html, pdf, csv
                //name: 'error.png',   // Optional: Custom filename for attachment
            }
        }, (error, event) => {
            console.log('errror', error)
        });
    };`